# Background image not found from my css file

Tags: css

My css file location htdoc/anyFolder/css/style.css and image folder file location 
htdoc/anyFolder/image/search.png. I used background-image rule in css file like `background-image: url("/image/search.png");`
but i does not find the image. Browser look for http://localhost/image/search.png while it should look for  http://localhost/anyFolder/image/search.png. Where is the problem. I tried

```
background-image: url("../image/search.png");

background-image: url("/../image/search.png");

background-image: url("./../image/search.png");
```

none of this work. Cannot find where is the problem. Does it depends on where  the css file is included.

Comment: change it to `background-image: url("/anyFolder/image/search.png);`

Comment: anyFolder/image/search.png and /anyFolder/image/search.png does not work. Is there any good way so that it does not depends on that anyFolder name

Comment: `none of this work` - Why do you think so?. In your last 3 options, can you tell us where does the browser look instead like you stated for your first option?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your paths are
`htdoc/anyFolder/css/style.css` and
`htdoc/anyFolder/image/search.png`

This should work:

```
background-image: url("../image/search.png");
```

This should also work:

```
background-image: url("/anyFolder/image/search.png");
```

But you say they didn't. You should check if the names of files and folders are correct and also if you have the `base` element on HTML, because it could change the path where the browser looks for files.

Comment: If you change the path and the browser still looks in the same path, could be a cache issue. Try cleaning your cache.

Comment: what do you mean by "base element on HTML" ?? cannot get it :(

Comment: `The HTML Base Element (<base>) specifies the base URL to use for all relative URLs contained within a document.` Read more about it here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base But if you don't know what it is, you probably don't use it, so it shouldn't be the problem.

Comment: Its was cache problem. sorry for bothering you guys :(

Comment: Relative path in link tag href does not work like when i use "../../css/style.css". 404 but when i use "/anyFolder/css/style.css" its works. php file path is htdoc\anyFolder\view\layout\main.php. Can you explain me why. Its not a cache problem. thanks in advance

Comment: If you use `/anyFolder/css/style.css`, the `/` on the start means you looking in the root folder, that's why it works. To use relative path, you should use `../../../css/style.css`. Every `../` means you up one directory.

Comment: at least i have got it in php it depends on base php file while my main.php is included form other directory's php file. thats why it was not working.

Answer (score 3):

> Does it depends on where is include the css file.

Yes. The path to your images is relative to where your css file is.

Just use:

```
background-image: url("../anyFolder/image/search.png");
```

Comment: sorry it does not work my question was is it depends on where the css file is included ??

Comment: Yes. The path to your images is relative to where your css file is. If your path starts with "../" you're using a relative path. If your path starts with "/", you're using an absolute path.

Comment: How about: background-image: url("../../anyFolder/image/search.png");

Comment: tried does not work. css file is included from htdoc\anyFolder\view\layout\main.php file. does it matters ??

Comment: That shouldn't be important. The important is where the css file is.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the html and css file in the same folder

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. please explain how your solution fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe late, but solution is:

```
      bacgkround-image: url(../search.png)
```

no need for "anyFolder","image"....

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are in the current directory where your file exist and try giving the link of an image by checking in current directory using ./ rather than copying the file path.This worked for me.